# Written Word Equation

Tags: code-golf, string, math, number

Word equations, but not as you know it! Given a sentence which will include two numbers, numerically, and a spelt operator, in the order seen in the examples, your goal is to give the numerical answer

The operators will be spelt as: "add", "minus", "times" and "divide"

Any <s>real number</s> integer may be used, as suggested by [caird](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) and [Jonathan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)

The solution must take one input and give one output

**Examples**:

```
Input: 7 add 8         Output: 15
Input: 9 times -2      Output: -18
Input: 24 divide 2     Output: 12
Input: 4 minus 5       Output: -1
```

You are not required to deal with divide by zero errors.

If you use a method that parses the expression, such as the python eval or exec, there will be no penalties, but if possible try to give a another interesting solution

**Scoring:**

Fewest bytes will win

Comment: Can we take input as `[7, 'add', 8]`? Or, perhaps less reasonably, as `[7, 8]` for one input, and `'add'` as a second input?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing the first one yes, as its still one input, the list, and it the correct order, but the second one no

Comment: @hyper-neutrino that's a fair point, I'm going to change it but leave a comment about it

Comment: @JonathanAllan [Real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) positive or negative rational numbers

Comment: @JonathanAllan as long as the input value is accepted and understood in your language it is fine. Precision is what your language can handle, where python has the maths module it gives pi as 3.141592653589793, but without the module it would not accept pi or any other constants so it cannot be expected for these to be inputs

Comment: It might be simpler just to limit the input to integers. I doubt it'll change any potential methods, but using "reals" or "decimals" can lead you to spend time/effort into specifying details such as format and precision, and using integers can allow more languages to take part that may not support floats/reals/decimals as easily

Comment: Can we omit the spaces in the input? e.g. `2times2`

Comment: @Shaggy no, they must be spaced or listed

Comment: Allowing `[7, 'add', 8]` but not three separate inputs is very unfair to typed languages like C.

Comment: @george As much as I appreciate you accepting my answer, I'd recommend against it. Generally, accepting an answer implies that the challenge is over (even years in the future), which contradicts our site policy of not declaring a a final winner and instead allowing challenges to be competitions within languages. That said, the decision to accept an answer is up to you, and you should feel free to do as you wish with the ability to accept/unaccept answers.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks for this comment, I had notification from PPCG that asked if I wanted to accept an answer so I thought it was the done thing. Thanks for letting me know otherwise

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
Ḣ€Oị2¦“×+ _÷”V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWPmtb4P9zdbXRo2aOGOYenayvEH97@qGFu2P/D7UcnPdw5QzPy//9oLs5ocx0F9cSUFHUdBYtYHSDfEsgvycxNLQaK6BqBhYxMgGIpmWWZKalAQYgYSCg3M68UpMwUKBILAA)

Takes input as e.g. `[7, 'add', 8]`. Requires no leading `0` for floats (e.g. `-.5` instead of `-0.5`)

### How it works

```
Ḣ€Oị2¦“×+ _÷”V - Main link. Takes a list [l, op, r]
Ḣ€             - First of each.
  O            - Convert to ordinal
    2¦         - To the element at the 2nd index (the op):
   ị  “×+ _÷”  - Index into the string “×+ _÷”
             V - Evaluate as Jelly
```

For example, consider `[7, 'add', 8]`. Getting the `Ḣ`ead of a number leaves it as is in Jelly, so `Ḣ€` turns this into `[7, 'a', 8]`. We then get the char code of each. Again, `O` leaves numbers as they are, so this maps it to `[7, 97, 8]`. We then change only the second element by indexing into `“×+ _÷”`. Jelly indexing is modular, so we get the \$97 \bmod 5\$th element of this list (i.e. the second, or `+`). This yields `[7, '+', 8]`, which we then concatenate into a string `7+8` and evaluate as Jelly.

Consider:

| Input operator | First character | Ordinal | \$\bmod 5\$ | Index into `“×+ _÷”` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `add` | `a` | 97 | 2 | `+` |
| `times` | `t` | 116 | 1 | `×` |
| `minus` | `m` | 109 | 4 | `_` |
| `divide` | `d` | 100 | 0 | `÷` |

Note that `0` maps to `÷` as 1-indexed modular indexing means that `0` is the last element

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 53 bytes

```
[ first3 swap first 5 mod { / * + 0 - } nth execute ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1NCsIwFATgvacYslSqUiv@HUDcuBFX4iI0rxpM05i8qrX07DXY3czHwBQy58r359PhuN8i0LMmm1PAjSx5afRXsq5swIO8JYNS8h3OE3PjvLaM3WjUYgUhlRJYo4ttA8G6pCCQpH9IMwilX1qRwCARSm3rOFmi6y8otA@8QHhLN@ToZaXQYoYxJpgjQQcbv@lDec2Ea5/BSudMg2lAbkj6/gc)

This is a port of @caird coinheringaahing's [Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235355/97916).

### Explanation:

It is a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a list of objects from the data stack as input and leaves an integer on the data stack as output. Assuming `{ 7 "add" 8 }` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `first3` Put the first three elements of a sequence on the data stack.

  **Stack:** `7 "add" 8`
- `swap` Swap the top two objects on the data stack.

  **Stack:** `7 8 "add"`
- `first` Get the first element of a sequence. (In this case, get the first code point of the string "add".)

  **Stack:** `7 8 97`
- `5 mod` Modulo 5.

  **Stack:** `7 8 2`
- `{ / * + 0 - }` Push a sequence with the possible mathematical functions. `0` is a filler that will never be selected because 3 is not a possible index.

  **Stack:** `7 8 2 { / * + 0 - }`
- `nth` Take an index and a sequence and return the object at that index.

  **Stack:** `7 8 +`
- `execute` Execute a word that is on the data stack.

  **Stack:** `15`

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
$0=/a/?$1+$3:/t/?$1*$3:/v/?$1/$3:$1-$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWP1HfXsVQW8XYSr8ExNICscpALH0gS8VQV8X4/39LS4WUzLLMlFQFSwA)

*Thanks to Dominic van Essen for the clue that cut 3 chars!*

```
$0=                                     -- Override $0, prints automatically
   /a/?$1+$3:                           -- If there's an "a" we add them
             /t/?$1*$3:                 -- If there's a "t" it's multiplication
                       /v/?$1/$3:       -- If there's a "v" it's division
                                 $1-$3  -- It must be subtraction...
```

If we have to make sure it will print in the event the operation yields `0` then it would be 2 characters longer, like this.

```
1,$0=/a/?$1+$3:/t/?$1*$3:/v/?$1/$3:$1-$3
```

Comment: Do you actually need the second ```$0=```?  [Without it](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxcBWP1HfXsVQW8XYSr8ExNICscpALH0gS8VQV8X4/39LS4WUzLLMlFQFSwA) seems to work Ok for 3 bytes less...

Comment: Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>86</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>74</s></sup> 73 bytes

```c
m;a;b;f(){scanf("%d %c%*s%d",&a,&m,&b);m%=5;a=m?m-1?m-2?a-b:a+b:a*b:a/b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLRboIwFH3nK25IMIAlSpVM1zEfln3F9KG0RZutaCjbyAy/PtYKMjZJbtrec869vZyyaM9Y2ypCSUZyPzhrRovcdz0OHvNC7XEXTSiaKDTJAqK8NCE0VRsVxSbwhkbZPZ2aCE3MMtK0sqhAUVn4AZwdMB870DKESuhqDim4d0A5h5VL/oGxBddQSSU0RPgGxxbHS@DyQ3IBt4SFJSxByeJdQ3ID65edIZwv90Bdx27B3bJoOoW9v6hPglWCd5I4QRDFKwQxtptmXJkdBHsVZUd0t/Uz3tbrJxOJi2B8Xri9Lj@W4NsmsuCiNrI56bcPoOWXOOb@tX0w6xPhkCEwnV7Y1787GtLU6ga9EHZkwG03bVBj79@kMMlh1v@qU2ko9iUYOx7Bvge9LcxUFQKNhsFFmupdX7Zxmra31/l10hmZ5gz@fLP8je51G33@AA)

*Saved a byte thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)!!!*

Inputs the equation as a string from `stdin`.
Returns the value of the input equation.

#### Allowing three parameters:

As allowed for untyped languages like this [PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235411/9481).

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>54</s> <s>52</s></sup> 51 bytes

```c
f(a,s,b)int*s;{a=(int[]){a/b,a*b,a+b,0,a-b}[*s%5];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFRb4IwEMff9ykuJJiCJQJK1DD2suxTKA@lLUoGaChsZISvPtYCMpxr0vR6v//d9a7UOlHadTEiWODISPLSFH5DAiStQ2g0ZBVhYsq9jLCNiRW1B1PoXui3nVRARpIcGdA8gVz0TAoTSi5KGwLQtkAYg53m/4GOgnsok4wLsNwH7iruboAlHwnj8ChYK8EGsiSvBHgPWBxCKWj6d@Ch4nC4w7Fuhwj1fl5fOS05G0IcD4Pl7DA4rjLaeWZ65vSdF4NQO9Zv7rHev8rtaRjm97U2xsWXAtQYZSHGaxlm@6P5DCL54pcY3cobq9FhTh4flstefZvurEmZa2i0F4T@xPuWJJ3a@k9AMbtzmFAFGUnTC0Vb2/hFQlCSx6jEms5ATwXoTMMLiiu8YMZ9SiFrxkihObkWksVI0@U3v4BKIo65nFaJQeBpoDwIRDiLigvOUTU62qe2@6ZxSk6isz5/AA)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!*
*Saved a byte thanks to [Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/johan-du-toit)!!!*

Comment: [52 btyes](https://tio.run/##bZDfboIwFMbv9xQnTTAFSwSUqGHsZtlTKBelf5RM0FDYyAivPlZAGdM1adqe3/ed03OYfWCsbSWmRJHYZEeaWyqoaYiTrNhFZk0XMaGW3vOYOITacbOzlOFHQdNqBaQ0ybAJ9RPo1buhEKpwIAS0Bso5bFBwB90ObqFIUqHA9h6413FvBTz5SLiAR8GyE6wgTbJSgf@A1S7Sgrr/BxkqDoc3HMtmcHT/F9VFsELwweL6BGx3Q8D1ukszzcyOgr2LfBCiffXm7avtq94@IjB9L9HVJ885dGPUhbiotM0JrtdnUMmXOEt8K28urgFrjAQwn/fq23QnTepcQ6O9IApG3rek6djWfwJGeHCXsQxTejqdGV475i9TitFM4oIgg4OhwOCIzBgpyYybf1MqXVPiDk3JJddMYqSt9gv0OfaZnlZBQJFxoCIMVTRxyVwIXF4DzVPTfjN5ogfV2p8/)

Comment: @Arnauld That's brilliant - thanks! :D

Comment: @JohanduToit Seeing as separate parameters are only *allowed* for those untyped languages that can extract them in order and this already is pushing past that boundary, think it's best to keep them in order. But nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: Maybe, the 74 bytes version, `"%d %c%*s%d"` is correct.

Comment: @tsh Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Expects a string.

```javascript
s=>([a,[b],c]=s.split` `,{a:a-+-c,t:a*c,d:a/c,m:a-c}[b])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEIXhfU8xZKVtohiUWsFeRASnk1giaqRJ3ZSePXUhXfiWj49/wBUdvczixWyVDn0dXH2PGuTNo@XU1i5xy2h8Bx3/YIXiIoj7Cs/EVYUp8Wn76LvhOJCdnR11Mtpn1EfsCqgUlAy2xTGkKWTF6WBu4M2kHQjJdiOy8ohkDsqsRmmQbA/Jo8lhMvPbQcHgHwo/)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Expects `[a, "operator", b]`.

```javascript
([a,[b],c])=>({a:a+c,t:a*c,d:a/c,m:a-c})[b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEEDRvadoWLU6ldBIxCZ4EcJinBZTQ6kRZGM8ey0LYsJfv/wHzjjSyz0nOQRjY1dH3iA0txaoFfWVf1DjgWDSuCcwGnMCr1HSVyQTKQxj6O2xD3fe8eYMLENjMmAVS7VCsDxnRbnbuEtyk/N2TFKq1cmi2kJ1StK42RmbqFqHausW5t3wXoYl@w/jDw)

Or [**41 bytes**](https://tio.run/##XczRCoIwFIDh@55ieLXVWeJIsoG9SHRxOpsx0S3SvImefU2QIP/rj7/FCQd6uscofTA2NnXkCJfbFUjUZ/5GjTuCUeOWwGjMCXqNkj4ikUjBD6Gz@y7cecOPwDI0JgNWsZQQLM9ZUW7@1Smp0fV2SE6qRcmiWjF1SM64yRmboFpmaqVm1Dv/mmcl@83iFw) if we can take 3 distinct parameters as input (as suggested by Shaggy).

Comment: Does taking input in the format `[7,'add',8]` save bytes?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've added a version using that format.

Comment: You could take them as individual arguments to save another byte, although you may want to ask for confirmation that that would be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 50 bytes

```java
(a,o,b)->o[0]<98?a+b:o[0]<'e'?a/b:o[0]<'n'?a-b:a*b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFda8IwFH3vr7j0xVTTTsQxtU4Zg8Fge/JRfLht0y6ubUqSCm7427vbrI6BL8k99@Occ5MjnjA8Zp@drBqlLRwJR62VZTSOPa9pk1KmkJZoDLyjrOHbA5C1FTrHVMBLW6cu5ZKgWH8iTz9Q7w@geA@TIKaGi0eHsWiJzk3l8AgdQ654EoQbtZ8e1svFFifJysUjMdri3RXUBMJkheOki3uiwdfAd1Iyg4rcsZ3Vsi5IGnVhgsHZmzR2/UqeC6E3gIaEn7TGs4nQ9DX2wGHJYTbnMHdeh5Ffsg2o5nbExyzzOfhWVsL0QSZPMhN9VMm6Nf5/oj/t5JZowSGckTiH@8CtBpArDe4hJXVPY7rW5Doy8kuwgOBkct0MYHc2VlSRam3UkFtb1iyPFKP2QlgmA967H@LIqmf6GKfPqJJcC8Fg9uL@6dL9AA)

Input is a `int, char[], int`.

- -36 bytes from @ceilingcat
- -49 bytes from @Kevin Cruijssen

#### Orignal: [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 135 bytes

```java
int o(int a,String o,int b){switch(o.charAt(0)){case'a':return a+b;case'm':return a-b;case't':return a*b;case'd':return a/b;}return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNbsIwEITPzVOscsEGkyJE1Z9QJI6V2hPHqgcndsPSJI7sDRVFPHtqQ4ADsmTPjke7n72RWzneqJ8Oq8ZYgo2vk5awTIZpFDVtVmIOeSmdgw@JNewjR5K812FNYFjYpViRxboAI0KZ8b37RcrXzCT5WtolsQnn@1w6PZCDF6uptTXIUZYerepqjXuLrtawt9TVus/SQ68n6aHrGXusrUEFlSdlJ6bPL5C2cNyDR@/oaP5Wky60XYB08ApLa@XOJdKFO/Yo4FnAdCZgxtNT/NRlAaa5jcdSqVhATFhpF4TCLSodVIV16@Jzk8vM7LbJk4Dx1A8V8ODj0bexcPxU9MlJ6o@5J00c/mnGfTkahafcrXaOdJWYlpLGA1JZM8N8rtDEkIuAe9HZWXI/4BBW9w8)

Simple switch

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZVFda8IwFH3vr7j0xVTTTsQxtU4Zg8Fge/JRfLht0y6ubUqSCm7427vbrI6BL8k99@Occ5MjnjA8Zp@drBqlLRwJR62VZTSOPa9pk1KmkJZoDLyjrOHbA5C1FTrHVMBLW6cu5ZKgWH8iTz9Q7w@geA@TIKaGi0eHsWiJzk3l8AgdQ654EoQbtZ8e1svFFifJysUjMdri3RXUBMJkheOki3uiwdfAd1Iyg4rcsZ3Vsi5IGnVhgsHZmzR2/UqeC6E3gIaEn7TGs4nQ9DX2wGHJYTbnMHdeh5Ffsg2o5nbExyzzOfhWVsL0QSZPMhN9VMm6Nf5/oj/t5JZowSGckTiH@8CtBpArDe4hJXVPY7rW5Doy8kuwgOBkct0MYHc2VlSRam3UkFtb1iyPFKP2QlgmA967H@LIqmf6GKfPqJJcC8Fg9uL@6dL9AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
exec'print '+''.join([`x`,'/*+ -'[ord(str(x)[0])%5]][type(x)==str]for x in input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBCsMgEEDRq8ymjDa2DdIuc5JhIFAtnSxU7CSY01vhb94vp35z8r3HFt9YqiQFnBDvW5ZkaG2rw8d1ghtSrsH8tJpmaWZ7eTGTniUOL8v4/MkVGkgalV2Ntb2TfzrAIIeEiA48/wE)

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##DchBCsIwEEDRq8xGZqKpStBlTxIGWkjEEUlCOpb09DHwN@@XQ985ud5LlaQQ9/VLiNdPlkR@aYvF2/kCE/pcA21aqRl/Z3N6Mns9Shye5/H5lSs0kDQqPyVjTO/ePSxgkF1CRAuO/w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 16 bytes

```
VaR+XL"/*+ -"@A_
```

Takes input as a single command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/LDFIO8JHSV9LW0FXycEx/v///5YKJZm5qcUKukYA)

#### Explanation

Uses the same "character code mod 5" trick as several other answers.

```lisp
 a                ; First command-line argument
  R               ; Replace all occurrences of
   +XL            ; the regex [a-z]+ (run of lowercase letters)
                  ; with the following callback function:
              A_  ;  ASCII code of the first character
      "/*+ -"@    ;  used as a (cyclical) index into that string
V                 ; After replacing, evaluate the resulting string as a Pip expression
```

---

If taking input as three separate arguments is allowed (e.g. if you can just type `python pip.py equation.pip 9 times -2` on the command line), then it's **15 bytes**:

```
Va."/*+ -"@Ab.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/LFFPSV9LW0FXycExSS/5////lv9LMnNTi//rGgEA)

And here's a solution without eval (using three separate arguments) in **18 bytes**:

```
[a/ca*ca+c0a-c]@Ab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/OlE/OVErOVE72SBRNznWwTHp////lv9LMnNTi//rGgEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
ǔ÷hC`/*+ -`iĖ
```

*-5 bytes thanks to inspiration from [@Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235461/112514)*

*-2 bytes thanks to @Steffan*

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwix5TDt2hDYC8qKyAtYGnEliIsIiIsIls3LCBcImFkZFwiLCA4XSJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBciIsIiIsIseUw7doQ2AvKisgLWBpxJYiLCIiLCJbNywgXCJhZGRcIiwgOF1cbls5LCBcInRpbWVzXCIsIC0yXVxuWzI0LCBcImRpdmlkZVwiLCAyXVxuWzQsIFwibWludXNcIiwgNV0iXQ==)

Pretty much a port of most of the other answers.

Explanation:

```
ǔ              # Rotate list to the right to get [r, l, op]
 ÷             # Pop then push each item onto the stack
  h            # Get the head (first item) of the operator
   C           # Convert to ASCII code
    `/*+ -`i   # Use that to index into the string "/*+ -"
            Ė  # Execute as Vyxal code (r flag reverses args)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python3 142 bytes**

```
def f():
a,b,c=input().split(' ');x=b[0];i=int(a);j=int(c);z=i+j if x=='a' else i*j if x=='t' else int(i/j) if x=='d' else i-j;print(z)
```

Splits tokens, applies operator and prints result

Comment: [111 bytes](https://tio.run/##LchLDoIwFEbhuav4Z7dVUEM0PmrdiHEAtI2XABJbDbL5SoTZOV/3DY9nm8VorIMTgzznSZGUelj7ruYgpOp1cdveFWtug8ilqv5RStW9xgCvKrBDf6GCbO0teDnBlfwMmwm0JjNLWkUn6IDcGBxJLsY5IXBjPdJs@mwHwx82FjPs0HD79tiTjD8) (Python 2), [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcjLDoIwEEDRvV8xu@koiEGMj1p/xLgA2oYhgMRWg/x8fcDu3tO/fXXvtiFoY8GKkU55VESlGteub9gLkoMqrpubZMWdFznJ@h8lyf7xC17VwBaGMxZoGmeAlxNc0M2QJJMohXqmuKZgBe4h1xoOSIvvHMFzaxzE6fRpBppfrA3MkEHL3dPBDil8AA) (Python 3)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 95 bytes

Fixed and -2 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Not too fancy, uses scanf and abuses memory by writing the whole string at the address of a char, mod 5 to get b in single digit range, then ternaries to pick the result.

I had a 0 as the true value for the innermost ternary.... But somehow gcc is perfectly happy without it, if anyone can explain how that works I would appreciate the comment.

```c
a,c;main(){char b;scanf("%d %s %d",&a,&b,&c);b%=5;printf("%d",b-2?b-4?b-1?b?:a/c:a*c:a-c:a+c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCoMwEEDRqwyBBK0zSIPdGCRnmZmgzaKhaHfFs8fg4u3@V9pUa2XU8OFcuv6vb95BwqFc1s7YBPYAmww6RifotA9il1f47rn87sCgkI9CU/OMEmcedeZHQ83QhrNWmjykDOQv)

Comment: Lol... for some reason I used add subtract multiply and divide. Fixed! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 55 bytes

```php
fn($a,$b,$c)=>[$a/$c,$a*$c,$a+$c,0,$a-$c][ord($b[0])%5]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxNDoIwEIbhfU8xIWMALQINRAyiB0EWpYXQBdD4d/06uCDBWXyzefLawbrLzQ6WMewr108BSo4tRxVW1xpljIqj3P/2QJvQj1A19fzQAbZ10oS7vHElY50aZsA@OHHwpdY@hwLoQjiCd5@8EuIY0nxlZ2IvM3ZPgpHYsigtVicygtp8jO5Iim1OrGxRo5neSy6H/5z7Ag)

uses the format `[7, 'add', 8]`

Nothing new under the sun, combines the tricks used in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array. Thought there might be some other clever way of working with the charcodes to get the required operator but using [caird's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235355/58974) of indexing into the operators seems to be optimal.

```
OvUg1_Îcg"/*+ -
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cVM&code=T3ZVZzFfzmNnIi8qKyAt&input=WwoiNyBhZGQgOCIKIjkgdGltZXMgLTIiCiIyNCBkaXZpZGUgMiIKIjQgbWludXMgNSIKXS1tUg)

Or without using `eval`:

```
rUj1 ÎÎcg"/*+ -
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cVMgb24gdm4&code=clVqMSDOzmNnIi8qKyAt&input=WwoiNyBhZGQgOCIKIjkgdGltZXMgLTIiCiIyNCBkaXZpZGUgMiIKIjQgbWludXMgNSIKXS1tUg)

```
OvUg1_Îcg"/*+ -     :Implicit input of array U
Ov                  :Eval as Japt
  Ug1               :  Modify the element at 0-based index 1 in U
     _              :  By passing it through the following function
      Î             :    First character
       c            :    Charcode
        g"/*+ -     :    Index into "/*+ -"
```

```
rUj1 ÎÎcg"/*+ -     :Implicit input of array U
r                   :Reduce by
 Uj1                :  Remove & return, as a singleton array, the element at 0-based index 1 in U
     Î              :  First element
      Îcg"/*+ -     :  As above
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ι˜`¨C"*+-÷"è.V
```

Input as a list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3M7TcxIOrXBW0tLWPbxd6fAKvbD//6OVLJV0lEoyc1OLgbSukVIsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/cztPz0k4tMJZSUtb9/B2pcMr9ML@6/yPjlYyV9JRSsxLAZIWSrE60UqWQFZJZm5qMZDWNQILGZkA2SmZZZkpqUAGRAwklJuZVwpSZqoUGwsA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ι               # Uninterleave the (implicit) input-list:
                #  [a,"O",b] becomes [[a,b],["O"]]
 ˜              # Flatten this list: [a,b,"O"]
  `             # Pop and push the three values separated to the stack
   ¨            # Remove the last character of the operator string
    C           # Convert it from a binary string to an integer
     "*+-÷"è    # Modulair 0-based index it into string "*+-÷"
            .V  # Evaluate it as 05AB1E code
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

| String | `¨` | `C` | Modulair 0-based index | Operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| and | an | 121 | 1 | + |
| minus | minu | 714 | 2 | - |
| times | time | 752 | 0 | * |
| divide | divid | 1331 | 3 | ÷ |

`C` on strings basically gets the index of each characters in the string `` 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzǝʒαβγδεζηθвимнт ΓΔΘιΣΩ≠∊∍∞₁₂₃₄₅₆ !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~Ƶ€Λ‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒĆŽƶĀ‘’“”–—˜™š›œćžŸā¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬λ®¯°±²³\nµ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ• ``, and then converts this list of indices to a base-2 integer.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 91 bytes

```
def f(a):a,b,c=a;b=b[0];d=b=='d';return(a+c*((b=='a')-(b=='m')))*[1,[c,1/c][d]][b=='t'or d]
```

Takes a single input as a listed of the values, i.e. `[7, "add", 8]` and returns the result of the equation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsQgEIbvfYpJL8AujXbdjWsbvPgK3pADBRo5lG2Amvj0deiaxkhCMuGbj/lh/s6ft/C0rtaNMFLNOs0HboTuBzHIR9VbMQhBLOmjy0sMVB/NgdJypglrtmIijLGDbLk0vH0wSlqlZAGZ3CJYtfowLzmBAFkBLimfORBtLeFwVRzai@K/4AVB9pNLiJoTsqa97vB0Rmr9l7cOcaHtaYeFTT4sxbxsIiJVVSNG8BwwAm5wYZlc1NnReybWbfocfci0fncpw5tODmo4QsqReoZF3dVsa4uuPGIsLn4N@6t@5F25w@JB07zuV6HM/inbPFPmpcUYl1IH9d4MQpTUslWMrT8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), 71 bytes

```
x,y,z=input().split()
print(eval(f'{x}{"/*+ -"[ord(str(y)[0])%5]}{z}'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0KnUqfKNjOvoLREQ1OvuCAnE0hzFRRl5pVopJYl5mikqVdX1FYr6WtpK@gqRecXpWgUlxRpVGpGG8RqqprG1lZX1aprav7/b66QmJKiYAwA)

Inspired by various other answers featuring `ord(str(y)[0])%5`.

If the input is taken as a list like `[5, 'minus', 8]`, then you can get an answer of only 67 bytes;

```
lambda l:print(eval(f'{l[0]}{"/*+ -"[ord(str(l[1])[0])%5]}{l[2]}'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHHqqAoM69EI7UsMUcjTb06J9ogtrZaSV9LW0FXKTq/KEWjuKRIIyfaMFYTKKOpagqUzYk2iq1V19T8/99cITElRcEYAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｎθ≡§Ｓ⁰aＩ⁺θＮmＩ⁻θＮtＩ×θＮdＩ∕θＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05qruDyzJDlDQcOxxDMvJbVCAywfXFKUmZeuoamjYKCpqVDNlZxYnKqglKhkpRAAlCjRcE4sLtEIyCkt1ijUUUA2URMIrKHKc1GV@2bm4Vdfgqo@JDM3Fa/6FFT1LpllmSmp2DXU/v9vopALcoCC6X/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Inputs the first number, switches on the string then inputs the second number as it outputs the result of the appropriate operation. 20 bytes with a boring eval-based approach:

```
ＩＵＶ⁺θ⁺§+-*/⌕amtd§η⁰ζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI6CyJCM/z7UsMac0sSRVIyCntFijUEcBTDuWeOalpFZoKGnraukr6Si4ZealaCgl5pakADkwyQwdBQNNTU0dhSpNELD@/99EITczr7RYwfS/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Gets the appropriate Python operator depending on the first letter of the string and evaluates the result as a Python expression.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 44 bytes

```perl
s/a/+/;s/t/*/;s|v|/|;s/n/-/;s/\pL//g;$_=eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCsIwEEbhfU7xL1wpcWpoUCneQG8gSCBBBtI0NDGrnN2xrh7fy2GNVqSQowNNhSrtt/TWqW9KpP/zme9E72n3uoXmosgZzntc1BWV51CgjTIjPDf2AUaNmDl9CizwXXLlJRXRMYt@2ONwGn4)